# What is π_1(BG) for an arbitrary topological group $G$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, fundamental-group

The classifying space $BG=|Nerve(G)|$ of an arbitrary topological group $G$ does not necessarily have the homotopy type of a CW-complex but the fundamental group should still be accessible. What is $\pi_{1}(BG)$? A reference on this would be great. My initial guess: $\pi_{1}(BG)$ is the quotient group $\pi_{0}(G)$ for arbitrary $G$

Motivation: There is a natural way to make $\pi_1$ a functor to topological groups. I am interested in relating the topologies of $G$ and $\pi_{1}(BG)$ but the topology on $\pi_{1}(X)$ is boring (discrete) when $X$ is a CW-complex.

Comment: Should that be $\pi_0(G)$? Since the universal bundle $EG$ is contractible, then the long exact sequence of homotopy groups break into
\[1=\pi_1(EG)\to\pi_1(BG)\to \pi_0{G}\to\pi_0(EG)=1.\]


Comment: Is it obvious that the function $\pi_{1}(BG)\rightarrow \pi_{0}(G)$ from the LES is a homomorphism?

Comment: @Jeremy, that it's a homomorphism looks fairly obvious to me --- but don't ask me why...

@Fei, following on Jeremy's remark, the proofs (e.g. of long exact sequence) are usually presented for topological groups of the homotopy type of a CW complex, which is a specialization explicitly excluded by the question as posed.

Put another way, it's not clear to me even that the sequence is *exact*.  Jeremy, just how arbitrary can these groups be?  Is a real algebraic group with the Zariski topology a case you want to consider?

Comment: In general, there is no map $\pi_1(BG) \to \pi_0(G)$. See my post below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If $G$ is homeomorphic to a Cantor set (e.g. $G=\mathbb Z_p$), then $BG$ contains a copy of the Hawaiian earrings in it. To see this, take a sequence of points of $G$ that converges to the identity element: you'll get a corresponding sequence of 1-cells in $BG$ that converge to the the degenerate 1-cell. The fundamental group of the Hawaiian earrings is a rather wild object, and looks nothing like the free group that you might naively expect.

If, on the other hand, if you agreed to redefine $BG$ to be the **fat** geometric realization of the simplicial space $NG$, then you would get $\pi_1(BG)\cong\pi_0(G)$, as desired.
I would even bet that the above isomorphism respects the natural topologies that are present on both sides.

Comment: Could you explain the subtelty between fat and ordinary geometric realization ?

Comment: Thanks very much Andre! The business about the geometric realization makes sense. I am not that familiar with fat geometric realizations but I believe the difference comes from restricting the identifications to only strictly increasing maps in $\Delta$ (correct me if I am wrong). Is there somewhere I can find a proof of the assertion about the group isomorphism?



Comment: I don't think that this "known". But I think that it's not too difficult prove it using transversality w.r.t the subset of centers of simplices.

Comment: @Andre: As you know, the usual geometric realization is given as a certain colimit (coend). I think it is possible to show that the fat geometric realization the same thing as (i.e. weakly equivalent to) taking the homotopy colimit of this same diagram. Right? If so, doesn't your claim follow from the weak homotopy invariance of the homotopy colimit? You simply replace G be a CW approximation. 


Comment: @Chris: I believe that you are correct. But viewing things up to weak homotopy equivalence would tend to forget the topology on $\pi_0(G)$, and I think that Jeremy cares about the latter.

Comment: To get a better homotopy type, one can alternatively replace $G$ by
the realization $G' :=|S.G|$, which is a topological group in the compactly generated topology ($S.$ = total singular complex, $| \quad |$ = realization). Then the map of topological groups $G'  \to G$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. Then the fat and thin realizations of 
$N.G'$ coincide up to homotopy.

Comment: I have a very retroactive, naive question about this answer. It seems like the fat realization is generally better behaved with the sole exception of being much bigger. Why is the thin realization insisted on so frequently?

Comment: @jdc: One advantage of the thin realization is that it commutes with products (Milnor's theorem) so long as you work in the category of compactly generated spaces. Another is that level-wise constructions, like level-wise loop spaces, give the right homotopy type (this is in May's Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces). I would agree with Segal (see the Appendix to Categories and Cohomology Theories) that the thick realization gives the correct homotopy type in general, and the thin version is a useful tool (e.g. for the previous reasons) when it's homotopy equivalent to the thick version.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas I never found a proof of Andre's general statement, so I gave a short proof in the appendix to my [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02613). (I prove the more general statement for arbitrary topological monoids with $\pi_0 G$ is replaced by its Grothendieck group.) In addition to using the thick realization, I needed to use the compactly generated topology on $G^n$ when forming the nerve $NG$; [I don't know if this matters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301847/). I haven't thought about whether my argument says anything about the topologized fundamental group.

Answer (score 15):

The first reference in this general area was:

> N. E. Steenrod, "Milgram's classifying
>   space of a topological group", Topology
>   7 (1968) 349–368.

Working in the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces, and
combining his Theorems 8.1 and 8.3 we have:

> Theorem: Let $G$ be a topological group with
>   unit $e$, such that $(G, e)$ is an NDR.
>   Then the canonical
>   map $EG \to BG$ is a
>   quasi-fibration and a principal
>   $G$-bundle.

The NDR-condition asks that the inclusion of $e$ in $G$ is
a cofibration.  That is of course weaker than asking for $G$ to be
a CW-space, but not as general as how the question was posed.

Since $EG$ is contractible, the long exact sequence in homotopy
for a quasi-fibration, at the usual base point of $BG$, gives a bijection
$$
\partial : \pi_1(BG) \cong \pi_0(G)
$$
of $\pi_1(BG)$-sets.  This at least gives you an isomorphism
between $\pi_1(BG)$ and some group structure on $\pi_0(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

Readers might also like to know a result on the first k-invariant of BG contained in

R. Brown and C.B. Spencer,  $\cal G$-groupoids, crossed modules
and the  fundamental groupoid of a topological group'', *Proc.
Kon. Ned. Akad. v.  Wet.* 7 (1976) 296-302.

This shows that the associated crossed module to fundamental groupoid of $G$ has   $k$-invariant which is exactly the $k$-invariant of $BG$.

Since this query is about non-connected topological groups, another related ressult is on universal covers of non-connected topological groups

R. Brown and O. Mucuk, ``Covering groups of non-connected
topological  groups revisited'',  *Math. Proc. Camb. Phil.
Soc*,  115 (1994) 97-110.

which relates the question of the existence of topological group universal covers of $G$ to the theory of ostructions to extensions of abstract groups.

Comment: I should have added that the $k$-invariant referred to is exactly the obstruction to there being a `universal covering' topological group $\tilede G$ of $G$ (in the sense that there is a morphism $p: \tilde{ G} \to G$ of topological groups which on each component is a universal cover of spaces).  

Comment: Misprint: $\tilede{ G}$ should be $\tilde{G}$.